# Traduzir retorno de data e manipular dias

Tags: html5, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

Estou usando um card que me retorna dados reais do dia, mês e ano. 
Na verdade são quatro cards, dois com ano e mês, e dois com ano, mês e dia.

O problema é que no meu retorno eu quero que exiba em português-BR e que eu possa manipular pra que consiga exibir não somente o dia atual, mas o de ontem (por exemplo). Estou usando no componente do html:

```html
{{ hoje | date:'MMMM' | uppercase }}
```

e no comoponente.ts eu declaro a propriedade hoje dessa forma:

```js
hoje: number = Date.now();
```

Dessa forma está sendo exibido: o dia atual ok
Ontem: não consegui achar uma forma de resolver pra que exiba
mês: como li na documentação, passei a referência de 'MMMM' para o mês ser exibido por extenso e no outro card somente 'MMM' para exibir as três primeiras letras. Me retorna respectivamente: September e SEP. Gostaria de ajustar as duas situações. Tradução e exibição para o dia de ontem. Já tentei injetando o `LOCALE_ID` no providers do meu AppComponent, setando para pt-br e agora com somente 'pt', mas sem êxito. Inclusive nas tentativas conforme alguns exemplos que vi, a data some  da exibição no browser quando eu faço a interpolação.

```
{{ hoje | date:'MMMM' | uppercase }}
```

-> SEPTEMBER eu preciso = SETEMBRO

```
{{ hoje | date:'MMM' | uppercase }}
```

-> SEP eu preciso = SET

```
<td rowspan="2" class="dia-setado">{{ hoje | date:'dd' }}</td>
```

-> 25 eu preciso dele mas também preciso de um que retorne a data de ontem.

Comment: Seria mais fácil vc postar qual é o formato do resultado que recebe e qual o formato que deseja mostrar na tela.

Comment: @LeAndrade pronto. Editei diretamente na pergunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Então chefe, não sei se entendi bem sua questão, porém, formulei uma resposta aqui baseado no que entendi, pode ver um exemplo [aqui](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-datas):

#### **Para traduzir o mês, no módulo, que pode ser o app.module**

- Importar o `LOCALE_ID`
- Importar o `registerLocaleData`
- Importar o `ptBr`
- Declarar o **registerLocaleData** passando o **ptBr**
- declarar um provider passando o **LOCALE_ID**

> Ficando da seguinte maneira seu módulo:

```
import { NgModule, LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';
...

import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import ptBr from '@angular/common/locales/pt';
registerLocaleData(ptBr)

@NgModule({
   ...
   providers: [{ provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'pt-PT' }],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

> No Html basta declarar

```
{{data | date: 'MMM' | uppercase}} - {{data | date: 'dd'}}
```

#### **Para mostrar, o dia anterior**

> No seu componente

```
ontem: Date = new Date();

ngOnInit() {
   this.ontem.setDate(this.ontem.getDate() -1);
}
```

> No seu Html:

```
{{ontem | date}}
```

Comment: Perfeito, valeu chefe!

Answer (score 1):

Olá, para fazer isto te sugiro duas formas. A Primeira seria setar o `locale` no Angular para ele traduzir para a língua desejada automaticamente. A segunda seria criar um array com os meses e utilizar uma função para traduzir a data.

Exemplo de como fazer da primeira forma:

```js
//app.module.ts
import { LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ ... ],
  declarations: [ ... ],
  bootstrap:    [ ... ],
  providers:    [{ provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'pt' }]
})



//component.ts
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import localeBr from '@angular/common/locales/pt';

export class AppComponent  {
  constructor() {
    registerLocaleData(localeBr, 'pt');
  }
}
```

Exemplo no stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lj7fg9

Comment: Valeu, cara! Me ajudou a ajustar o ```LOCALE```